# Why isn't my outlook addin creating a ribbon section?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook

I've tried to port over some code that worked in Visual Studio 2013 and adapt it for a new project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with the Office developer addin.

I'm not quite sure what I've done differently, but this time round Outlook 2013 isn't displaying the ribbon tab that I created. It's not disabled, and it's not available in the "Customize Ribbon" dialogue either.

Sorry to be so vague, but I'm at a loss as to what to check and where to start to resolve this. I've attached a quick screengrab showing the tab I was hoping for and the debugger attached to the right outlook instance.

[image: in debug, attached to the correct pid, nothing showing].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any UI errors?

By default, if an VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also you may find the [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx) helpful.

Comment: I've followed the instructions to show me any errors, and none pop-up or anything, but is there a debug window in outlook or VS that I should be looking at to see them?

Comment: turns out i hadn't set the RibbonType variable and it was putting the ribbon only in the readmail windows by default!https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398246(v=vs.120).aspx